# Effect of duty ratio on buck converter with battery load

Tags: buck

[image]Will the battery charging circuit be able to supply charging current if the duty ratio is adjusted to 0.1?

Comment: this question needs a circuit diagram to answer or more information. At the moment it is too open-ended.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give much information : what are the voltages of your voltage source ? Of the battery ?
Let's say the input voltage is E=14V, and the battery voltage Vb=12V.

If your duty cycle is D=0.1, you will get a small charging current, because your buck converter will operate in discontinuous mode, which means that the current will be non-zero only during a small part of the period.
If you want to operate in continuous mode, you must have at least D*E>Vb.

The two operating modes are explained in the  [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter) article. See figure 6 : you can operate at an output voltage close to maximum, but in discontinuous mode, and at a (very) lowcurrent.

Comment: Why will it operate in discontinuous mode - this depends also on the value of the inductor if it is a non-synchronous buck converter. The op never said it was a synch converter.

Answer (score 1):

OK, circuit supplied!

While the non-synchronous converter is switching it will "produce" inductor energy. This energy will transfer to the load and this means it will always supply *some* charging current but this current reduces as duty cycle reduces.

If the MOSFET (whose gate is tied to ground), were in fact a synchronizing MOSFET (turned on when the pass transistor turned off), then this could be different. Under these circumstances, if the input voltage \$\times\$ the duty cycle is less than the battery voltage, then the switching elements would discharge the battery.

Assuming for one minute that it *is* a synchronous converter, given the values you have shown, 75V \$\times\$ 0.1 = 7.5V and this will discharge the battery. If your duty cycle were 16% then there would be no average current into or out of the battery.

However this isn't true of a non-synchronous switcher; the energy you supply to the inductor has to be passed to the load (minus the loss in the forward diode hidden inside the gate-grounded MOSFET).